# React Native "interactive" keyboardDismissMode throws error when dragged

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

The error is: `RCTLayoutAnimationGroup expects timings to be in ms, not seconds`

This occurs as I drag the keyboard downwards quickly. Sometimes it happens; sometimes it doesn't.

I am using a simple TextInput component, within a KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: How quickly are you dragging it down? If it is quicker than 10ms then it will throw that error. Line 92.

Otherwise, if you've set a delay between 0 and 0.01 it will also throw the same error: Line 98 - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTLayoutAnimation.m

If its none of the above, can you provide the code throwing that error?

Comment: @Vlad Some of my beta testers are dragging the keyboard down quickly, and that error is throwing.  How can I fix it or patch it?

Comment: @Vlad I haven't set any delay ; I don't even know what that is

Comment: It is hard to diagnose without knowing exactly how it is set up. Can you provide some code or a simple project which replicates the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding bounces={false} to your ScrollView seems to solve the issue.

```
<ScrollView keyboardDismissMode="interactive" bounces={false}>
```

It changes the behaviour a bit as well but, the error doesn't seem to appear anymore.

I think if you wish to keep the 'bouncy' behaviour of the ScrollView, the best way would be to make the 'bounces' dependent on the keyboard show. When the keyboard is shown, the bounces is set to false. Have a look at my sample component:

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    bounces: true
  }
  this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this));
  this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
}

_keyboardDidShow(){
  this.setState({bounces: false});
}

_keyboardDidHide(){
  this.setState({bounces: true});
}

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}  behavior="padding" enabled>
      <ScrollView keyboardDismissMode="interactive" bounces={this.state.bounces}>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, width: 150, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
      />
      </ScrollView>

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

A RNT hack would be to override the duration when it is less than 10(ms). For you it should be to change: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView.js method: *scheduleLayoutAnimation* change:

```
const {duration, easing, endCoordinates} = event;
```

to:

```
let {duration, easing, endCoordinates} = event;
```

and add:

```
if(duration < 10){
    duration = 10;
}
```

inside the ***if (duration && easing)*** condition.

This will make sure the shortest duration is 1ms and never less, thus the duration is not going to be thrown anymore.

My *KeyboardAvoidingView.js*, *_onKeyboardChange* method looks something like this:

```
_onKeyboardChange = (event: ?KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event == null) {
      this.setState({bottom: 0});
      return;
    }

    let {duration, easing, endCoordinates} = event;
    const height = this._relativeKeyboardHeight(endCoordinates);

    if (this.state.bottom === height) {
      return;
    }

    if (duration && easing) {
      if(duration < 10){
        duration = 10;
    }
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
        duration: duration,
        update: {
          duration: duration,
          type: LayoutAnimation.Types[easing] || 'keyboard',
        },
      });
    }
    this.setState({bottom: height});
  };
```

**EDIT 2:**

I submitted an issue to RNT team, and opened a PR to them: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/21858

**EDIT 3:**
The fix was merged to react native master: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/87b65339379362f9db77ae3f5c9fa8934da34b25

Comment: Should I report this bug to React-native? Surely I'm not the only person in the world with the need for drag to dismiss.  Why isn't this a bigger issue?

Comment: Yeah, this looks like RNT bug to me as well. I am not sure why it isn't a bigger issue, maybe because it is intermittent, isolated to IOS and an input inside a scroll view. Let me know if the above workaround worked for your beta tester.

Comment: @TIMEX have a look at my edit. It shows where to override the RNT code to avoid this exception, keeping the bounce.

Comment: I think I am going to log the issue on their github and submit a PR to have it fixed in upcoming versions. I'd reference this thread if you don't mind.